# ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, sql, datetime

```
['BBBBB', '20190213', 'SUCCESS', 'Job_name1', '2019-02-14 18:11:55', '2019-02-14 18:11:56', '0.02']    
['AAAAA', '20190213', 'SUCCESS', 'job_name2', '2019-02-14 18:11:48', '2019-02-14 18:11:50', '0.03']
['AAAA', '20190213', 'WAITING', 'job_name4', 'None', 'None', '0']
```

I have a list of DB results like above,records 4,5 are in UTC time zone and are strings

```
def save_jobs_to_file(jobs_info, filename):
        '''save jobs to file
        saved to file in re-arranged order: 1 - 0 - 3 - 3 - 4 - 5 - calculated run time
        '''
        from datetime import datetime
        import pytz
        tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
        utc = pytz.utc
        logging.warning('Saving jobs to file {0}...'.format(filename))
        f = open(filename, "w+")
        for line in jobs_info:
            #print(line)
            for i in range(len(line)):
                if line[i] == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    #print(datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                    print(type(line[4]),type(line[5]))
                    line[4] = datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    line[4] = utc.localize(line[4])
                    line[4] = line[4].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    line[5] = datetime.strptime(line[5],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    line[5] = utc.localize(line[5])
                    line[5] = line[5].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            line = "|".join(line)
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
        logging.warning('Completed saving jobs to file {0}!'.format(filename))
```

I am trying to changing   4,5 records to datetime objects  using strptime function and again converting them to pst time zone dattime object and converting them string again using strftime().

also, my list has None values at 4,5 records,though i am checking the None Values, still strptime is throwing the below error.

```
(<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./heart_latest_dev_get_pc_jobs.py", line 239, in <module>
    main_program()
  File "./heart_latest_dev_get_pc_jobs.py", line 222, in main_program
    save_jobs_to_file(enhanced_jobs,filename)
  File "./heart_latest_dev_get_pc_jobs.py", line 104, in save_jobs_to_file
    line[4] = datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

i am new to Python, glad i made it work part of it but i am not able to figure out what i am doing wrong, though i am passing a string to strptime and checking the None Values.

As recommended by @John Anderson

I hope i have implemented correctly what he suggested but i am still getting the same error:

```
Edit(1):

def save_jobs_to_file(jobs_info, filename):
    '''save jobs to file
    saved to file in re-arranged order: 1 - 0 - 3 - 3 - 4 - 5 - calculated run time
    '''
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    utc = pytz.utc
    logging.warning('Saving jobs to file {0}...'.format(filename))
    f = open(filename, "w+")
    for line in jobs_info:
        #if line[0] != None:
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if  line[0] != None:
                #print(datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                #print(line[0])
                #print(type(line[4]),type(line[5]))
                line[4] = datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                line[4] = utc.localize(line[4])
                line[4] = line[4].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                line[5] = datetime.strptime(line[5],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                line[5] = utc.localize(line[5])
                line[5] = line[5].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        line = "|".join(line)
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
    logging.warning('Completed saving jobs to file {0}!'.format(filename))
```

Error after edit(1):

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./heart_latest_dev_get_pc_jobs.py", line 240, in <module>
        main_program()
      File "./heart_latest_dev_get_pc_jobs.py", line 223, in main_program
        save_jobs_to_file(enhanced_jobs,filename)
      File "./heart_latest_dev_get_pc_jobs.py", line 103, in save_jobs_to_file
        line[4] = datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
        (data_string, format))
    ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'



 *****Any help would be much appriciated :)*****
```

Comment: In the first iteration of your `for` loop, `i` is `0`, and you check if `line[0]` is `None`. If `line[0]` is not `None`, then you process `line[4]` and `line[5]` without checking if they are `None`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, Thanks for reply, But looks like i am getting the same error :(

Comment: Your last DB entry does have 'None' as its 4th entry. I guess it is the one that triggers the error.

Comment: did you fix your issue?

Comment: @Debendra, Not yet. :(

Comment: @Demi-Lune, Yes Especially line[4] and line [5] has None Values in some records thats why i am "pass"ing if line[i] == None.

Comment: can you show your expected value as string.

Comment: So now your code is specifically checking if `line[0]` is `None`, but you are still not checking `line[4]` or `line[5]`. And your `for i in range(len(line)):` loop is just repeating that same code several times. If you are concerned about `line[4]` is `None` or `line[5]` is `None`, then that is what you should check for.

Comment: @SomanathPatil Then the test was probably `'None' in line` not `line[0] == None` . It seems that you mixed `None` and `'None'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   import pytz
   for line in jobs_info:
        #print(line)
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if line[i] == None:
                pass
            else:
                #print(datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                print(type(line[4]),type(line[5]))
                try:
                    line[4] = datetime.strptime(line[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    line[4] = pytz.utc.localize(line[4])
                    line[4] = line[4].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    line[5] = datetime.strptime(line[5],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    line[5] = pytz.utc.localize(line[5])
                    line[5] = line[5].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                except:
                    pass
        line = "|".join(line)
        print (line)
```

Result:

BBBBB|20190213|SUCCESS|Job_name1|2019-02-14 18:11:55|2019-02-14 18:11:56|0.02
AAAAA|20190213|SUCCESS|job_name2|2019-02-14 18:11:48|2019-02-14 18:11:50|0.03
AAAA|20190213|WAITING|job_name4|None|None|0

Comment: ncica, thats what i am doing :)

Comment: @ncicia, its compiling without any errors but , i still don't see line[4] and line[5] in pst, even in your result the records ( line[4] and line[5] are in GMT only)

Comment: @ncicia, its worked i missed to add line[4] = line[4].astimezone(tz) :)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing "pass" with "continue",
"pass" is only a placeholder and thus the expressions before "else" would still be executed